# add external opencv libraries to ros package

Tags: ros, opencv, external-libraries, libopencv, target-link-libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all
i use opencv libraries in ros qt package . i need to use surf feature detector in my work but libraries of this function not exist in ros_opencv . i want to add external opencv libraries to package but i can't this .
can anybody help me ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54026/add-external-opencv-libraries-to-ros-package/) by [abrsefid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1260/abrsefid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need external libraries for SIFT and SURF. Just add  `#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>` and it will work. You initialize your fdeature detector and descriptor using : `cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detect = new cv::SurfFeatureDetector;` and descriptor : `cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> detect = new cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor;` You could replace the word Surf with Sift or Orb for the feature detector. And you could also replace the descriptor with Sift or Brief.

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2013-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akali](https://answers.ros.org/users/21316/akali/) on 2015-01-15**:
where do i add the red code lines on?